# Xamarin BLE Plugin: ListView not displaying info of scanned devices

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using BLE Plugin for Xamarin to scan for devices. I then want to list the Id of the devices. However, my ListView is not displaying the Id (just displays empty fields).

Cs:

```
        IBluetoothLE ble;
        IAdapter adapter;
        ObservableCollection<IDevice> deviceList;
        IDevice device;

        public BltScan()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ble = CrossBluetoothLE.Current;
            adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
            deviceList = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
            bltlist.ItemsSource = deviceList;

            scan();
        }

        public async void scan()
        {
            try
            {
                deviceList.Clear();
                adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
                {

                    deviceList.Add(a.Device);
                    // DisplayAlert("Disc", a.Device.Id.ToString(), "OK");
                };

                //We have to test if the device is scanning 
                if (!ble.Adapter.IsScanning)
                {
                    await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Notice", ex.Message.ToString(), "Error !");
            }
        }
```

XAML:

```
        <ListView x:Name="bltlist">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Id}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I can make an alert when adding the devices to deviceList and it displays the scanned device's Id correctly.

Even more: I made a wrapper class that stores an IDevice, and it's Id as String and still the ListView doesn't display the Id. I can even enter a non-existing field in `Text="{Binding GarbageField}"` and it will no complain but just list all devices withour displaying anything.

I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMbb5FwGWSw and https://github.com/didourebai/BLEPluginDemo and have seen in the youtube comments that others have had the same struggle. But I couldn´t find any answers to the problem.

Comment: does `IDevice` have a public property named Id?

Comment: Yes! I can also read it out in the DisplayAlert(...) line that's now commented out

Comment: please post the code for IDevice and it's implementation

Comment: It's part of the library I use: https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le. You can find the declaration at Source/Plugin.BLE.Abstractions/Contracts/IDevice.cs

Comment: without trying it myself it's hard to say what's wrong.  Your code looks correct.  What happens if try another Property of IDevice, like Name?  Or just hardcode a value in the Label instead, does that display?

Comment: Name doesn't work either. Hard coding also doesn't work. It doesn't even notice when you bind to a field that doesn't exist.

Comment: It doesn't even work when I add an own dummy device of my own type. So whenever a device is scanned, I add a device of type DummyDevice to the list that just contains hard coded field values that have nothing to do with BLE.

Comment: if hard coding a value doesn't work then something is wrong with your ItemsSource

Comment: Ugh, I'm so stupid. I now set the text color explicitly to black and it works for the name. Id still isn't displayed, which is really weird.

Comment: What could be wrong with the ItemsSource. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: if you want to share your code I'll take a quick look.  If a hardcoded value doesn't display then that implies that the ListView has no rows, which means something is wrong with ItemsSource.

Comment: Ok thanks! https://github.com/ferk0l/datauploader/

Comment: The relevant code is in BltScan

Comment: I think the listview has rows because you can see the delimiters. Now that's also evident because the Names are displayed (Text) but the Ids not (Detail)

Comment: very weird - it just doesn't want to display GUIDs.  You might want to submit that as a bug to the XF team

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help! Ill do that and post here if I hear something back

Comment: Can you share a test project about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In case you didnt get it to work. 
You could also make a collection of string and just add and remove from that list upon new device found.
When user then clicks a device get the ID in that list and get the same ID from the devices list